# Simple form of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What is a simple form of this ring: $$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}][x]/(5,x^2+1),$$

I know that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}][x]=\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y^2-2)$. Probably, I should use second theorem of isomorphism, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the fact that you can mod out in any order, and use the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}][x]/(5,x^2 + 1)\cong\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(5,x^2 + 1,y^2 - 2)$. I'll start you off:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}][x]/(5,x^2 + 1)&\cong\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(5,x^2 + 1,y^2 - 2)\\
&\cong\mathbb{F}_5[x,y]/(x^2 + 1,y^2 - 2)
\end{align*}
Now look at these polynomials. What can you say about the quotient of $\mathbb{F}_5[x,y]$ by either? Another hint: you'll want to use the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings) eventually.

Comment: To finish it: the ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{25}\times\mathbb F_{25}$.

Answer (score 3):

You can write it as $$\mathbf F_5[x,y]/(x^2+1,y^2-2).$$

As $y^2-2$ has no root in $\mathbf F_5$, it is irreducible over $\mathbf F_5$ and $\mathbf F_5[y]/(y^2-2)$ is a field, isomorphic to $\mathbf F_{25}$.

As for $x^2+1$, it has  roots in  $\mathbf F_5$ ($\pm 2$), so the quotient $\mathbf F_5[x,y]/(x^2+1,y^2-2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf F_{25}[x]/((x-2)(x+2))\simeq\mathbf F_{25}[x]/(x-2)\times\mathbf F_{25}[x]/(x+2)$  by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and the latter is isomorphic to $\mathbf F_{25}\times\mathbf F_{25} $.

Comment: $x^2 + 1$ isn't irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$. $x^2 + 1\equiv x^2 - 4\pmod{5}$

Comment: Oops! Sorry I didn't check my computations (it's late…) Thank you for pointing that. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Well you know that:

$\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^2+1) = \mathbb{Z}[i]$

$\mathbb{Z} / (5) = \mathbb{Z}_5$

Comment: So, it give: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}][x]/(5,x^2+1)\cong \mathbb{F}_{5}[\sqrt{2},i]$. I need to express this in form $A\times B$ etc. using irreducibility of some polynomials etc.

Comment: Not quite. $\mathbb{F}_5$ already has $i$ in it, so $x^2 + 1$ isn't irreducible after you mod out by $5$...